# ArcPad - VBscript - Autopopulate attributes

Tags: vbscript, arcgis

I am using the following script to grab parcel and address information from one layer to fill the attribute table of a newly created feature.

There is no returned error, but the problem I am having is that there seems to be the wrong information stuck in the memory of recordselect function. No matter where I place a point it gives the same parcel # and address. Or maybe it isn’t actually be performing the IF function properly.

```
Sub Address

Dim rsCurrentXY
Set rsCurrentXY = Map.Layers("Violations").records
rsCurrentXY.movelast
Dim objXYShape
Set objXYShape = rsCurrentXY.Fields.Shape
Dim pControls
Set pControls= Application.Map.selectionlayer.Forms("EDITFORM").Pages(“PAGE1”).Controls
Dim rsGrid
' Find corresponding map page to the valve point
Set rsGrid = Map.Layers("ACPA_parcels").records
rsGrid.movefirst

Do While Not rsGrid.eof
If rsGrid.fields.shape.Ispointin(objXYShape) Then
pControls("txtAddress").value = rsGrid.Fields("ADD1").Value

Exit Do
End If
rsGrid.Movenext
Loop


' Clean Up
Set rsCurrentXY = Nothing
Set objXYShape = Nothing
Set rsGrid = Nothing
End Sub
```

(I have another subroutine called "PIN" that would do the exact same thing.)
I have them called when their respective edit boxes in the custom form are activated by the inspector.

Thanks for the help,
Robert

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the EDITFORM via Application.Map.selectionlayer.Forms("EDITFORM") will be problematic. Whenever working with controls on an EDITFORM you should using ThisEvent.Object to discover all your objects. For example, if your event handler is Page_OnLoad then ThisEvent.Object will refer to your current page. You should have code like this:

```
Dim pPage1
Set pPage1 = ThisEvent.Object
Dim pControls
Set pControls = pPage1.Controls
```

Comment: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/65742-Filling-in-atrributes-for-a-point-layer-from-a-underlying-polygon-layer?p=228353&posted=1#post228353

Comment: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/65742-Filling-in-atrributes-for-a-point-layer-from-a-underlying-polygon-layer?p=228353&posted=1#post228353